# Create buffer in Metres

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer, europe

I want to create a buffer in meters around points in Europe. But I cannot find a proper CRS for Europe that is in meters instead of degrees?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use one of the LAEA or LCC Europe projections:

```
EPSG 5633, 5635, 5636, 5638 LAEA Europe
```

[image: laea]

```
EPSG 5632, 5634, 5637, 5639 LCC Europe
```

[image: lcc]

All EPSG codes of the same type seem to have the same projection parameters.

ESRI also offers projections Europe_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic (102013) and Europe_Equidistant_Conic (102031), but they almost look the same.

Comment: that is the exact base map I am looking for. Do you know a link where I can download that shapefile?

Comment: I just took Natural Earths world_boundaries, selected European countries by rectangle, and saved the selection to a new file. They also offer the 10 degree grid named ne_110m_graticules_10.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use Geographic Coordinate Systems which are for locating points on a sphere (over-simplification). In order to do buffers and measurements, you need to use a Projected Coordinate System, which flattens the sphere out to plane.  All projections will introduce some distortion in shape, area, distance, and/or direction.  You simply have to select one that looks the best for your purpose.  Andre has suggested several. You can also create your own custom projection.  ESRI has put out a nice pdf you can find [here](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/710Understanding_Map_Projections.pdf) that explains map projections and might help you to better understand and select/create an appropriate one for your purposes.