# Making a buffer - degrees instead of meters

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer

I just started working with GIS very recently.

I'm trying to create a buffer of 200m around the points of the layer "vlaamse venen naamloze laag". But in the distance box, the program will only allow me to create a buffer in degrees? I checked the project properties, but they are in meters.

[image: screenshot of the creation of the buffer]

I tried using this question, ([gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/create-buffer-in-metres](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97225/create-buffer-in-metres)) but I can't figure it out. 
Changing the CRS of the layers makes that the distance is put in meters but then i have a different problem. If I change them (e.g. to Lambert 72 or Lambert 2008), my layers dont overlap anymore, which they should.

Comment: Buffers are based on the layers CRS, which is 4326, which is based on degree. Save your data in a different, meter-based CRS (don't just set it to one), then buffer.

Comment: Also, on the question which CRS to use, please refer to [epsg.io](http://www.epsg.io)

Comment: The emphasis on Erik's comment should be on the word "layer." The buffer algorithm uses the CRS of the *layer*, not the CRS of the project. Reproject your layer into a CRS that uses meters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: I tried changing the CRS of the layer into a CRS that uses meters. Now the buffer indeed is in meters, but the points from the layer "vlaamse venen naamloze laag" are not overlapping with my DTM anymore now (while they should). Is it possible that it has something to do with my layer with the points? I imported it from google maps as a .kmz file.

Comment: Don’t change the projection, reproject rather the layer as @Erik suggested

Comment: problem solved, thank you very much all!